# MVC Download File Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, download, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to download a file from a javascript function. I see plenty of examples of the server side code and I think I have that working fine.

```
public ActionResult DownloadReport(LongParameterValueModel reportId)
    {
        Boolean isZipFile = false;
        String extension = "";
        String fileName = "";
        String contentType = "";
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = ReportRecord.GetReport(Session["bankId"].ToString(), reportId.Value, out isZipFile, out extension, out fileName))
            {
                if (isZipFile)
                {
                    // download instead of open in browser
                }
                else
                {
                    if (extension.ToUpper() == "PDF")
                    {
                        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                        {
                            FileName = fileName.Replace(",", ""),
                            Inline = true,
                        };
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                        contentType = "Application/pdf";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                        {
                            // for example foo.bak
                            FileName = fileName.Replace(",", ""),
                            Inline = true,
                        };
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                        contentType = "text/plain";                            
                    }
                }

                return File(ms.ToArray(), contentType);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

What I haven't been able to find is how to call that client side to return the PDF/txt data in a new window. I am currently using:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DownloadReport", "Search")',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            Value: dataItem.ID
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

            var w = window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data);
            //var w = window.open('about:blank', 'ReportViewer');
            //w.document.write(data);
            //w.document.close();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

but nothing happend. The commented version opens a blank window but nothing gets written to it (or if it does it doesn't show the PDF or txt file).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going open a new window with the PDF, why not serve it over HTTP instead of downloading it in JavaScript? I.e. you could do `window.open('http://yoursite.com/report/10')` and serve the PDF as a static file there.

Comment: There are some security concerns with having links to the files. It was determined to be safer to write the binary output to the browser so there wasn't a link associated with a particular file.

Comment: Unless you are counting on security trough obscurity you aren't really improving security with this. In the end you are calling the same function with the same ID, the only difference is that you are using a POST request instead of a GET request and that the ID parameter is part of the request body instead of the URL. Any scriptkiddie can reverse engineer that in 10 mins.

If you want to be safe implement some kind of security mechanism like user permissions or one time download keys that invalidate once the url has been used.

Comment: So I take it you don't know how to use this method from the client side?

Comment: What method are you taking about?

Comment: The 'public ActionResult DownloadReport()'. I want to use it to write the binary output to a new window.

Comment: I have no idea how ASP.NET works. What I do know is that you can just create a link to the method that returns the file and open that link in a new window. I.e. `<a href="path-to-file-download" target="_blank">View report</a>`. There is absolutely no reason to use JavaScript for this. Any security concerns you'll need to address on the server.